# Prove that $ST$ is antiparallel with $PQ$

Tags: geometry

Given is $\triangle PQR$ with altitudes $PS$ and $QT$. Prove that $ST$ is antiparallel with $PQ$.

*What I've done up until now:*

- Given: $\triangle PQR$ with altitudes $QT$ and $PS$
- What to prove: $P_1 = S_2$ (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBU88.jpg) for the image)

I want to prove this with extremely basic mathematics, because my book solves this using the reverse of Thales' theorem, and cyclic quadrilaterals and such, and I believe there must be a simpler way to prove this, I however can't figure out how. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Sorry, my drawing is incorrect. $ \angle P_{12} $ must be equal to $\angle S_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Triangle PQR and two heights]
Looking at the figure above, we need to prove that $$\delta = \beta + \gamma.$$

From the figure we can deduce that $\triangle RSP \sim \triangle RTQ$ and
$\triangle SOQ \sim \triangle TOP$.

So we can conclude that
$$\frac{a}{a'}=\frac{b}{b'}$$
Let's rearrange that proportion in this way:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'}$$
But by the picture
$\angle QOP = \angle SOT$ (vertically opposite angles).
Therefore
$$\triangle POQ \sim \triangle TOS$$
Now we can conclude that
$$\beta = \mu$$ and
$$\alpha = \theta.$$
Applying the exterior angle theorem in $\triangle TQS$ we get:
$$\delta = \mu + \gamma \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow \delta = \beta+\gamma$$
Therefore $ST$ and $PQ$ are anti-parallel with respect to $RP$ and $RQ$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the picture from Ricardo's answer.

Draw a circle of diameter PQ. Since $PTQ =90^\circ$, $T$ is a point on this circle. $PSQ =90^\circ$, $S$ is a point on this circle.

Thus $PQST$ are on the same circle, and hence $\angle TPQ + \angle TSQ =180^\circ =\angle RST + \angle TSQ$$